# Getting Full User Name

Tags: environment-variables, username, version-control

How do I look up my full user name in Ubuntu? I want this information to propagate to the environment variables `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME` and `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL`.

Comment: What do you mean by full user name?

Comment: Like "Peter Jackson" instead of, say, the variable `USER` set to `pejack`.

Comment: It's often nicer to see full names in commit logs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These fields in the `/etc/passwd` file are called GECOS fields. Unfortunately, I cannot find a single command to get this single field such as the full name. I believe this cannot be done without using shell scripting. Below are two approaches.

- Parse `passwd` directly:

  ```
  getent passwd $USER | cut -d ':' -f 5 | cut -d ',' -f 1
  Gert van Dijk
  ```
- Use of `finger`

  ```
  finger -m $USER | head -n 1 | sed 's/\(.*\)Name\:\s\(.*\)$/\2/g'
  Gert van Dijk
  ```

Related question on SO: [What's the easiest way to get a user's full name on a Linux/POSIX system?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/833227/1254292)

For programming in C, this *is* more elegant by using [`getpwnam()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwnam).

---

But really, for use in Git for a single user do:

```
git config --global user.name "Your Full Name"
git config --global user.email "user@example.tld"
```